# Push Notification: Fatal error: Class 'EccFactory' not found in pushnotification/vapidkeys.php on line 124

Tags: php

I am trying to implement push notification.

I downloaded web-push library from: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php

The first thing I wanted was VAPID keys .

filename is vapidkeys.php, this file is inside pushnotification directory, and in pushnotification directory I have web-push-php-master directory.

```
<?php
    require('web-push-php-master');
    use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;
    var_dump(VAPID::createVapidKeys());
?>
```

But the above line throws following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'EccFactory' not found in pushnotification/vapidkeys.php on line 124
```

Please help me solve this issue, I am new to push notification and namespaces

Answer (score 1):

You have to get web-push-php with Composer, so that all the dependencies are installed.

1. Install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)
2. Run `composer require minishlink/web-push`. This will install web-push-php and all its dependencies in the `vendor` folder.
3. In your PHP file, require it : `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Here's a basic example that uses web-push-php: https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPD Website Only Generate Key,Your website is HTTP can't  generate Key

Comment: My site is https site